# Chaining multiple hadoop jobs and submitting without waiting

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm trying to figure out how to chain multiple hadoop jobs, with the output of one step feeding into the the input of the next step. A lot of stuff I've found by googling says that I should either call them one at a time from a single thread and wait for completion, or that I should use Job.addDependingJob() and then submit them. I've opted for the latter, but I can't seem to get subsequent jobs to execute after the previous one has finished.

Here's my code:

```
List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();

for(int i = 0; i < stepCount; i++) {
    JobConf jc = new JobConf(clusterConfig);

    ... set up mappers and reducers here ...

    ... set up input and output paths here ...

    Job j = new Job(jc);
    j.addDependingJob(jobs.get(jobs.size() - 1);
    jobs.add(j);
}

for(Job j : Jobs) {
    JobClient client = new JobClient();
    client.init(j.getJobConf());
    client.submit(j.getJobConf());
}
```

All the jobs run at once, and I get output like this:

- No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
- Total input paths to process : 1
- Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
- No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
- Total input paths to process : 0
- Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
- No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
- Total input paths to process : 0
- Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
- No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
- Total input paths to process : 0

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I'm using Hadoop 0.20.205

EDIT for clarification: I need to be able to submit a job chain to the cluster, and then return immediately without waiting for the job chain to complete.

Answer (score 2):

JobControl should be used to set the dependencies between the jobs. The dependencies aren't set in the given code, so the jobs are running in parallel instead of running in a sequence. If there are more complex work flows then Oozie can be used.

[Here](http://cloudcelebrity.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/how-to-chain-multiple-mapreduce-jobs-in-hadoop/) is an interesting article on the same.

Comment: JobControl works for the job ordering, but I need to be able to submit the job chain to the cluster and return immediately (rather than wait for job completion). Will JobControl or some other madoop mechanism be able to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few years since I've dealt with this, but I see a couple things:

1. Your errors don't have anything to do with chaining between jobs. Make sure you can get a single job to run before worrying about chaining them.
2. Jobcontrol doesn't (or at least didn't in 2010) submit the sequence of jobs to the job tracker, it is just a tool to handle checking when upstream jobs have completed and automatically submitting the next to the job tracker. You will not be able to just run it and exit.
3. You should not be calling submit on the jobs. That submits them to run. You should be passing off control to job control somewhere in there.

I thought this was confusing, and started writing my own DAG helpers in https://github.com/kevinpet/jobcontrol which you may or may not find useful.

Answer (score -1):

Following is way of chaining map reduce jobs . Here we are running second job on the output of first job:

```
        Job job1 = new Job(conf, "job1");
    Job job2 = new Job(conf,"job2");
    job1.setJarByClass(driver.class);
    job1.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job1.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    job1.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job1.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    String outputpath="/user/hadoop/firstjoboutput";
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputpath));
    job1.waitForCompletion(true);

    job2.setJarByClass(driver.class);
    job2.setMapperClass(SecondMap.class);
    job2.setReducerClass(SecondReducer.class);
    job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job2.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path(outputpath));
    String finaloutput="/user/hadoop/finaloutput";
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(finaloutput));


    System.exit(job2.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```